# How to make Twitter like HTML prompt?

Tags: html, twitter, prompt

How can I use Twitter kind of HTML prompt for my app?

You can see this prompt message while deleting your tweet.

I have seen this style of alert box in the new version of Wordpress and its also used in Gmail.

Kindly help to figure this out.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear: what are you looking for? The ability to use in-HTML pop up dialogues, or are you looking to replicate the look an feel?

Comment: I want this look and feel Paul. It will be good if I can replace/override all my browser based alerts with this style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's prompt style of Firefox 4. Every `alert('some thing')` become such kind of popup. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this tutorial.  Not far from what you are asking for.  This is a simple confirm dialogue based on some images and CSS with JQuery. So should be very easy for you to customise.

http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/

If you are looking for much more sophistication then look in to JQuery UI.